# SharePoint 2010 to 2013 - How to keep the same URL during migration

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, upgrade, url, alternate-access-mapping

I am working on building new 2013 farm. How do I handle URL because in DNS it can only be routed to one server? Any good article or steps on this can help me a lot.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Lot of people work with temporary URLs on the new farm (e.g. `http://portal-2013.company.local`). I am not a fan of this method, as i have seen lots of trouble when changing from temporary URL to final URL during go-live.

I prefer to set up the new farm with the same URL as the old farm. To get things to work, I add all SharePoint URLs with new IP-Addresses to the HOSTS-File on all servers and test-clients. This makes testing more challenging, as you cannot access the new farm on any client.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend the how you migrating the database attach method or 3rd party tool,also how big is your migration window ( also how much data).

Two popular Method being used

1. Using the temp URLs: build a SharePoint 2013 farm, configure all the service application and web applications etc. Now create the Temp DNS for SharePoint 2013. use that and test the farm. On day of migration, while you migrating the data from 2010 to 2013 in one window...Update the 2010 DNS record -> point it to SharePoint 2013 servers. Test it
2. Using the Host file entries: Instead of using the temp url use the host file entries on the client machine to access & test the 2013 web application. But you have to update the DNS record and point to 2013 server ont he migration cut-over time.

I followed the method 1, its worked for me all the time as all my migration within one window and SharePoint 2013 was a fresh farm( no old customer data over there). i had no hard-coded URLs because hard-coded url breaks in test migration.